# Prove that $\left (\frac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{a+b+c} \right) ^ {(a+b+c)} > a^a b^b c^c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Prove that $\left (\dfrac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{a+b+c} \right) ^ {(a+b+c)} > a^a b^b c^c$ if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are distinct natural numbers.  Is it possible using induction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to read the answer from [here](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/161/articles/Riasat_BasicsOlympiadInequalities.pdf). section Weighted AM-GM Inequality :) it is a good one .

Comment: nice link! (+1)

Comment: @downvoter why (-1)?

Comment: wasn't me but I guess because the linked page is no longer available

Comment: @Iuli Answers that only include a link are bad, for exactly this reason - very often the page that was linked to disappears. Can you edit your answer so that it's useful again?

Answer (score 8):

Rewrite it as:
$$
  \left( a \frac{a}{a+b+c} + b \frac{b}{a+b+c} + c \frac{c}{a+b+c} \right) > a^\frac{a}{a+b+c} \cdot b^\frac{b}{a+b+c} \cdot c^\frac{c}{a+b+c}
$$
This is [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):
$$
    \log\left(\mathsf{E}\left(X\right)\right) > \mathsf{E}\left(\log\left(X\right)\right) \quad \text{or}\quad \mathsf{E}\left(X\right) > \exp \left( \mathsf{E}\left(\log\left(X\right)\right) \right)
$$
where $X$ is the random variable which can assume one of three possible values $\{a,b,c\}$ with respective probabilities $\{ \frac{a}{a+b+c}, \frac{b}{a+b+c}, \frac{c}{a+b+c}  \}$.

Comment: @Fixee Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)